# Different post views for different category views

Tags: posts, categories, pages

In my blog, my "pages" are really just posts sorted by categories. What's the best way to change the way the posts look for one of my category pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For styling archive index pages for a given category, target `body.category-slug` (where `slug` is the category slug) in CSS.

For styling single blog posts that have a given category, assuming your post container is a div, target `div.category-slug` (where `slug` is the category slug) in CSS.

For PHP operations, you can also use `is_category( 'slug' )`, which returns true if you are on the archive index page for a given category, and you can use `in_category( 'slug' )` which returns true if the current post is in a given category.

Comment: Cool! Just what I was looking for.